# How to escape reserved character on command line or shell script in linux?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, wildcards

It is known that the character (!) Is reserved, the curious thing is that it works on the common user, but does not work as root, I tried some approaches to solve my problem, but without success, I would like to know if it is possible to escape these characters .

The command I'm trying to execute is simple, a move ignoring some specific files.

```
 mkdir --parents www/; mv !(init.sh|environment.sh|docs|www) $_
```

Comment: Do you really want to escape it - or do you want it to be interpreted as a KSH-style extended shell glob? Perhaps the issue is that the root shell is different from that of your common user (a different shell, or the appropriate shell option not set)?

Comment: I didn't know KSH, did a quick search, installed the package, and with a little adaptation it worked for me.

In that case what should I do, answer the question with the solution or delete it?

Comment: The command would have worked in `bash` too, if the `extglob` shell option was set, and in `zsh` if the option `KSH_GLOB` was set. It's unclear what shell your "common user" is using and how it's configured, and how this differs from the shell that the root user is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with escaping the `!` character.

The `ksh` shell implements some extended globbing patterns, and `!(...|...|...)` is one of these.  The pattern matches anything not matched by any of the patterns in the parenthesis.

Some shells are able to use `ksh` globbing patterns.  For example, setting the `extglob` shell option in the `bash` shell (`shopt -s extglob`) enables these, as does setting the `KSH_GLOB` shell option in the `zsh` shell (`setopt KSH_GLOB`).

The shell that your root user is using obviously does not enable the use of `ksh` globbing patterns, and it is unclear whether it's even able to (the `dash` shell, for example, don't have this ability). Your ordinary user, on the other hand, seems to have enabled these patterns by default, either by virtue of running the actual `ksh` shell, by explicitly enabling the correct shell option in a shell initialization file, or by using some third-party extension that quietly enables the shell option by default.

Comment: Also note that bash-completion (third party completion extensions for bash) enables `extglob` which is one way that option may be enabled without one being made aware of it.